# How to running to start build android use cordova

Tags: android, cordova

Its so noobs, I don't know how to start to build an application. I was finished [Installing cordova](http://learn.ionicframework.com/videos/windows-android/) actually i need help for :

1. Is't start at index.html in folder myapp/www ?
2. Where I can preview my work?
3. Once I finished, How to run on my phone?

Comment: open the  `index.html` in your webbrowser

Comment: The index.html doesn't at my xampp folder (htdocs) ? If I move it, is need to config something?

Comment: You cannot move the index.html file. NOTE: if you open the html file, you can only see the layout; none of the plugins works - unless you have an emulator. There are many emulators available. Google: [Phonegap emulator](https://www.google.com/search?q=Phonegap+emulator)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use myapp/platforms/android/assets/www in order to make changes and view them through you mobile phone.

Comment: Yes, I use command at myapp $ ionic serve, and know it show localhost with another port and preview of my code. Now I must find how to my www being an apk

Comment: that's pretty straightforward, you need to import your project's android folder as a Project to android studio or eclipse adt. that should work.